# Simple one. How to remove horizontal gap between floating divs with tables inside

Tags: html, css

Ok, so, I have this simple HTML with DIVS, and tables inside those DIVS. I want them to be next to each other so I used CSS float. I can't remove the gap between the tables, and I want them to be separated just as they are.

Any ideas?

```css
    @charset "utf-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    div {
      float: left;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <table width="328" height="450" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" height="41">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Custo benefício</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Intermediário</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Alto Desempenho</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" height="8">RODAPE</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table width="226" height="450" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="41">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="8">RODAPE</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table width="163" height="450" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="41">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Viseiras e reparos</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Motoclubes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="8">RODAPE</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table width="263" height="450" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="41">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="8">RODAPE</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is how it looks:
[ScreenShot](http://prntscr.com/4jb6p0)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could provide a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I don't see any gaps using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/et0hfh6o/

Comment: Here goes the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b33j5cwd/

Comment: Ok so, adding this CSS reset worked like a charm!: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
 cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
```

to all of your table tags. This should remove any small spaces you might be having. It should look something like this:

```
<table width="328" height="450" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/54aq3p86/

(I added a border in the fiddle so you could tell where the border's are)

Comment: `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` attributes on the `table` tag are deprecated.

Comment: Yet works too.. still I went to this solution: Add this CSS reset to your CSS code: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css

Answer (score 0):

Take a look At these code I just change the inline div style.
And Make the table border 1px to visible

Untitled Document

```
<body>
<div>
<div style="float:left">
<table width="328" height="450" border="1px">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" height="41">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Custo benefício</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Intermediário</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Alto Desempenho</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" height="8">RODAPE</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div style="float:left">
<table width="226" height="450" border="1px">
    <tr>
        <td height="41">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="8">RODAPE</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div style="float:left">
<table width="163" height="450" border="1px">
    <tr>
        <td height="41">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Viseiras e reparos</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Motoclubes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="8">RODAPE</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div style="float:left">
<table width="263" height="450" border="1px">
      <tr>
        <td height="41">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="8">RODAPE</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but, where is that inline div you changed?

Comment: I just use the <div> style in every <div>
And At last I just change this 
<div style="clear:both"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you only want to remove those two gaps right!?, not the ones provided by the cells!

here is a jsfiddle for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/4gLm20zq/1/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/4gLm20zq/1/)

Just add the cellpadding and cellspacing table atributes, just like I did in the jsfiddle example. I also added a class name to each div except for the main parent div. and added some new css rules. Give it a try and let me know if this works for you.

Here is the CSS

```
<style>
    div.column {
      float: left;
    }
    div.column:nth-child(even) {
        margin: 0px -2px;
    }
    td {
        background-color: #CCC;
    }
</style>
```

And here is the html

```
<div>
<div class="column">
<table width="328" height="450" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" height="41">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Custo benefício</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Intermediário</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Alto Desempenho</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" height="8">RODAPE</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div><div class="column">
<table width="226" height="450" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
        <td height="41">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="8">RODAPE</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div><div class="column">
<table width="163" height="450" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
        <td height="41">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Viseiras e reparos</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Motoclubes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="8">RODAPE</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div><div class="column">
<table width="263" height="450" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
      <tr>
        <td height="41">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="8">RODAPE</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```